# Error en código de práctica, recursividad

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo ejercicios para practicar JavaScript y he realizado el siguiente, solo que no funciona para ciertos casos y no encuentro el error.

**Secuencia inventada:** `f(n) = (f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3)) x 2`

Donde las primeras tres posiciones son dadas por el arreglo recibido por parámetro y, a partir de la siguiente, se calcula como la suma de los 3 números anteriores multiplicados por dos.

`array` es un arreglo de 3 posiciones que puede contener números o cadenas, aquellas posiciones que sean números debemos dejarlas tal cual están, pero las que tengan cadenas, debemos calcular su cantidad de caracteres para usarlos en la secuencia.

Por ejemplo si recibimos: `["Franco", 1, "Henry"]`, deberíamos tener los siguientes 3 valores iniciales de la secuencia `f(0) = 6, f(1) = 1 y f(2) = 5`, ya que "Franco" tiene 6 caracteres y "Henry", 5.

A partir de ahí la cuarta posición sería  (6 + 1 + 5) * 2 = 24 y así sucesivamente.

La función `secuenciaHenry` debe devolver el enésimo numero de la serie, por ejemplo para el arreglo antes mencionado: secuencia: 6, 1, 5, 24, 60, 178, 524

- secuenciaHenry(0) // 6  ya que el elemento de la posición 0 es cero
- secuenciaHenry(1) // 1 ya que el elemento de la posición 1 es 1
- secuenciaHenry(6) // 524 ya que el elemento de la posición 6 es 524

Para números negativos de n debe devolver false

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
function secuenciaHenry(array, n) {
  // Tu código aca:
  if(n<0) return false;
  if (n>=0 && n<3) {
   if (typeof array[n] === "string") {
     return array[n].length }
     else { return array[n] }
   }  
  if (n>=4) {
    return 2*(secuenciaHenry(n-1) + secuenciaHenry(n-2) + secuenciaHenry(n-3))
   }
 }
```

Comment: El codigo no funciona cuando se le pasa n = 6 y  array = ["Franco", 1, "Henry"], ya que deberia devolver "524" y no lo hace.

Comment: Tampoco funciona cuando se le pasa n es 7 y array = ["Asd", 1, "Hi"], ya que deberia devolver 756 y tampoco lo hace.

Comment: me duele ver que la funcion devuelva false o un numero... eso es un NO....

Comment: El planteamiento no es muy claro y el código incorrecto, porque cuando `n` es mayor de 3 usas `n` en lugar de los elementos del arreglo para realizar los cálculos, además de que no envías los parámetros correctos en la llamada recursiva, falta enviar el arreglo.

Comment: Podrias ayudarme a dejarlo mejor? Como lo cambiarias? @Triby

Comment: Lamentablemente, no entiendo el planteamiento y no puedo ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que como menciona el compañero @Triby, en los casos en que `n` es mayor o igual a 3, no le pasas los parámetros necesarios a la función para que pueda hacer el cálculo.

La firma de la función es:

```javascript
function secuenciaHenry(array, int);
```

Por lo que la función **siempre debe recibir dos parámetros**, el primero un array con los elementos iniciales y el segundo un número entero para calcular el elemento *n*.

Ahora que sabemos que `secuenciaHenry()` debe recibir dos parámetros, entonces podemos corregir el error:

```js
function secuenciaHenry(array, n) {
  if(n < 0) return 0;
  // if(n < 0) throw new RangeError('n debe ser mayor o igual a 0');

  if(n >= 0 && n < 3) return typeof array[n] === 'string' ? array[n].length : array[n];

  return ((secuenciaHenry(array, n-1) + secuenciaHenry(array, n-2) + secuenciaHenry(array, n-3)) * 2);
}

function mostrarSecuenciaHenry(array, n) {
  console.log(`Secuencia: [${array}]`);
  for (let i = -2; i <= n; i++) {
    console.log(`f(${i}) = ${secuenciaHenry(array, i)}`);
  }
}

mostrarSecuenciaHenry(["Franco", 1, "Henry"], 10);
mostrarSecuenciaHenry(["Asd", 1, "Hi"], 10);
```

La función `mostrarSecuenciaHenry()` simplemente es un auxiliar que mostrará el valor de la secuencia desde `-2` hasta `n`. El `-2` es meramente ilustrativo para demostrar que la función devuelve `0` cuando `n` es menor a 0. Esto para tratar la discrepancia que menciona el compañero @gbianchi. Otra posible solución, sería que en lugar de devolver un valor numérico, lances un [error de rango](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RangeError) por ejemplo.